# MySQL query - derived table vs left join where

Tags: mysql, sql

Given `posts` and `posts_tags`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    external_id varchar(10) UNIQUE,
    title varchar(255),
    body TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE posts_tags (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    post_external_id varchar(10) REFERENCES posts(external_id),
    tag varchar(255),
    UNIQUE KEY (post_external_id, tag)
)
```

As you can see the above tables store posts and their tags for a backend serving REST APIs.

There is a `get-post-by-external-id` API that will return the post with its tags identified by the post's `external_id`. Given this use case, I'm wondering which query below executes faster and consumes less resources?

## Derived table

```sql
SELECT posts.*, posts_tags.tag 
FROM (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE external_id = ?) AS posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_tags ON posts.external_id = posts_tags.post_external_id
```

## Left join where

```sql
SELECT posts.*, posts_tags.tag 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_tags ON posts.external_id = posts_tags.post_external_id
WHERE posts.external_id = ?
```

I'm not sure, but I guess the `WHERE` filters the intermediate results after the `LETF JOIN` happens?

Comment: Define what "*better*" means for you.

Comment: @PM77-1 Query executes faster and consumes less resources on the MySQL server?

Comment: Should it also return the correct result? The last one is not equivalent to the first two. Means - it can return a different result.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You are right. My mistake. The query should return the post row even if the post has no tag in the `posts_tags` table. The second query is incorrect regarding the purpose. Let me update the question.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for pointing out, wrong syntax let me update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a subquery. The engine doesn't evaluate/execute the query in the same order as you write. The optimizer will generate an "execution path" as optimal as possible (though it doesn't work perfect). However for this particular case it's documented in [WHERE Clause Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/where-optimization.html):

> For each table in a join, a simpler `WHERE` is constructed to get a fast
>   `WHERE` evaluation for the table and also to skip rows as soon as
>   possible.

So your guess:

```
I guess the WHERE filters the intermediate results after the LETF JOIN happens?
```

is wrong. Given an index on `posts.external_id` the engine will only "touch" the matching row(s) and perform the join with `posts_tags` only for that/those row(s).

And from my experience I can also tell you, that the second (trivial) query is perfectly fine performance wise.

I would though not use that query for another reason. You get the post data duplicated per related tag. Consider you have a post containing a 10KB text and having 10 tags. You will get 10 rows (one per tag) with the same text and fetch together 100KB of data. Then you will need to write code to "deduplicate" the data.

I would rather either run two separate queries:

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts 
WHERE posts.external_id = ?
```

and

```
SELECT posts_tags.tag 
FROM posts_tags
WHERE posts_tags.post_external_id = ?
```

and "merge" the result in application code

or aggregate the tags with GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT posts.*, GROUP_CONCAT(posts_tags.tag) as tags
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_tags ON posts.external_id = posts_tags.post_external_id
WHERE posts.external_id = ?
GROUP BY posts.external_id
```

or with JSON_ARRAYAGG()

```
SELECT posts.*, JSON_ARRAYAGG(posts_tags.tag) as tags
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_tags ON posts.external_id = posts_tags.post_external_id
WHERE posts.external_id = ?
GROUP BY posts.external_id
```

Parsing a comma delimited list or a JSON array should be simple in any application language.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the informative answer. I have one follow-up question. Since the `WHERE` optimization quote mentions a simpler `WHERE` will be constructed for *each* table. So I'm wondering if the query will be more efficient if the `WHERE` clause also mentions the `posts_tags` table, ie. `WHERE posts.external_id = ?` becomes `WHERE posts.external_id = ? AND posts_tags.post_external_id = ?`

Comment: That condition would be redundant with `posts.external_id = posts_tags.post_external_id` in the ON clause and also convert the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN, since it will remove the NULL rows.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: The updated answer is very helpful. I also have the concern for the duplicated large info returned with each tag. I didn't know the `GROUP_CONCAT` and `JSON_CONCAT` functions, and I will use the `JSON_CONCAT` function if the elements in the json list is in order, however it is not: `The order of elements in this array is undefined`. I guess I will do two queries and then perform merge in the application code.

Comment: Yes that's a known issue. You can either sort the array in application code or use `GROUP_CONCAT(posts_tags.tag ORDER BY posts_tags.tag)` or `CONCAT_WS('', '[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_QUOTE(posts_tags.tag) ORDER BY posts_tags.tag), ']')` ;-(

Comment: Wonderful! I just tried on MySQL 5.7.25, I eventually use `CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_QUOTE(posts_tags.tag) order by posts_tags.id),']')` for the grouping, and `GROUP BY posts.id` instead of `GROUP BY posts.external_id` due to error "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.posts.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".

Comment: I thought `posts.external_id` is either PK or at least UNIQUE since you have a foreign key on it in `tags`. If it's UNIQUE and NOT NULL then it would work. But `GROUP BY posts.id` is also fine. But note that you might asking for troubles, when you reference a non unique column (set) as foreign key. In (some) other DBs it'S not even possible.

Comment: Your are completely right. I just had a look at the column defs and found that the `posts.external_id` currently does not have the `NOT NULL` constraint...